# How to get a page's title which in iframe?

Tags: jquery, html, dom, iframe, title

first I have a simple iframe

```
<iframe src="http://www.google.com"></iframe>
```

I also have a button to alert the google's title

```
<input type="button" value="gettitle" />
```

then I want use jquery to get the iframe inner html's title

```
    $("input ").click(function () {
        alert($('iframe').contents().find("title").text());
    });
```

But it doesn't work,what's wrong with this code?How can I get the title correctly?

[Here the online case](http://jsfiddle.net/hh54188/TAtQT/)

Thank you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Same origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy) will prevent you from doing that if the page in your `<iframe>` element doesn't come from the same domain as your main page. Since your example uses `www.google.com`, it won't work.

That said, your code is correct and should work as expected when the two pages come from the same domain.

Answer (score -1):

see http://jsfiddle.net/TAtQT/7/

Comment: You should post your code here, no exclusively on the fiddle. Furthermore your code doesn't work for me.